# Filter and order Query in SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

When I use .filter or .order in my queries, Xcode always return me an error like :

.order : Value of type 'AnySequence' has no member 'order'.
My Query is : `for nb in try database.prepare(Tcourse).order(course)`

.filter : Cannot convert value of type 'Expression' to expected argument type '(Row) throws -> Bool'. My query is : `for nb in try database.prepare(Tcourse).filter(course == courseactu)`

Here is my code :

```
 import UIKit 
 import SQLite

class CourseViewController: UIViewController {
    var database : Connection!
    let Tcourse = Table("Tcourse");
    let id = Expression<Int>("id");
    let course = Expression<String>("course");
    let nbparc = Expression<Int>("nbparc");

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do{
            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("users").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
            let database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
            self.database = database
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
let courseactu = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "CourseActu") ?? ""
        do{
            for nb in try database.prepare(Tcourse).order(course) {
                print("\(nb[nbparc])")
            }

            }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Edit : 
Without .filter or .order my query works.

```
database.prepare(Tcourse)
```

Comment: What 3rd party SQLite library are you using?

Comment: @rmaddy This one : https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#sqliteswift-documentation). You don't call `filter` or `order` on the result of `prepare`.

Comment: You are a genius !!! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rmaddy

The answer is :

```
for nb in try database.prepare(Tcourse.filter(course == courseactu))
```

.filter is in the same brackets as the table name!